# Can the bold sentence be rewritten like this?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Today I read [a paper](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/10/3/661/1635350?login=true) having the paragraph as below.

> Firms may be financed by their suppliers rather than by financial
> institutions. There are many theories of trade credit, but few
> comprehensive empirical tests. This article attempts to fill the gap.
> We focus on small firms whose access to capital markets may be limited
> and find evidence suggesting that firms use more trade credit when
> credit from financial institutions is unavailable. Suppliers lend to
> constrained firms because they have a comparative advantage in getting
> information about buyers, they can liquidate assets more efficiently,
> and they have an implicit equity stake in the firms. Finally, **firms
> with better access to credit offer more trade credit**.

My focus is the last sentence, can it be rewritten as " firms with **worse** access to credit offer **less** trade credit"?

Answer (score 2):

"̶F̶i̶r̶m̶s̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶s̶e̶ ̶a̶c̶c̶e̶s̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶c̶r̶e̶d̶i̶t̶ ̶o̶f̶f̶e̶r̶ ̶l̶e̶s̶s̶ ̶t̶r̶a̶d̶e̶ ̶c̶r̶e̶d̶i̶t̶.̶"̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶g̶r̶a̶m̶m̶a̶t̶i̶c̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ ̶c̶o̶r̶r̶e̶c̶t̶.̶ ̶H̶o̶w̶e̶v̶e̶r̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶d̶o̶e̶s̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶n̶e̶c̶e̶s̶s̶a̶r̶i̶l̶y̶ ̶m̶e̶a̶n̶ ̶e̶x̶a̶c̶t̶l̶y̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶.̶

F̶o̶r̶ ̶e̶x̶a̶m̶p̶l̶e̶,̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶I̶ ̶s̶a̶i̶d̶ ̶"̶r̶e̶d̶ ̶h̶o̶u̶s̶e̶s̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶p̶r̶e̶t̶t̶y̶,̶"̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶d̶o̶e̶s̶ ̶*̶*̶n̶o̶t̶*̶*̶ ̶*̶n̶e̶c̶e̶s̶s̶a̶r̶i̶l̶y̶*̶ ̶m̶e̶a̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶b̶l̶u̶e̶ ̶h̶o̶u̶s̶e̶s̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶u̶g̶l̶y̶.̶

I̶f̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶s̶a̶i̶d̶ ̶"̶f̶i̶r̶m̶s̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶b̶e̶t̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶a̶c̶c̶e̶s̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶c̶r̶e̶d̶i̶t̶ ̶o̶f̶f̶e̶r̶ ̶m̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶t̶r̶a̶d̶e̶ ̶c̶r̶e̶d̶i̶t̶"̶,̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶*̶p̶r̶o̶b̶a̶b̶l̶y̶*̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶*̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶n̶e̶c̶e̶s̶s̶a̶r̶i̶l̶y̶*̶ ̶m̶e̶a̶n̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶f̶i̶r̶m̶s̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶s̶e̶ ̶a̶c̶c̶e̶s̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶c̶r̶e̶d̶i̶t̶ ̶o̶f̶f̶e̶r̶ ̶l̶e̶s̶s̶ ̶t̶r̶a̶d̶e̶ ̶c̶r̶e̶d̶i̶t̶.̶

Yes, the sentence can be rewritten like that.

Comment: thank you and I understand what you mean. However, FMHO, "blue" and "red" can not be compared, but "worse", "better", "less", "more" are comparative adjectives so I think it may work in my case. Please correct me if I fall into a fallacy.

Comment: You know what, I think you're right. I think I was wrong.

Comment: I agree with @MathewAlden has said. I'd also like to add that if you were to write that alternate sentence, what the vast majority of people would say wouldn't be "worse" but "**poorer**" instead. When it regards "access," for whatever reason, the vast majority of people consider the opposite of "better" to be "poorer," not "worse." "Worse" even sounds a bit uneducated when referring to "access (e.g., *poorer* access to healthcare, poorer access to the street, etc.). Google Ngram backs this up, showing that "poorer access" is used three times more often that "worse acess."

Comment: @Benjamin Harman Huh. In my dialect, the opposite of "better" is "worse", but I ain't gunna argue with Google Ngram. Thanks for your perspective!